# PCAP not downloading in proper format via Python API call

Tags: python, api, download, pcap

I have the following module I built that makes an API call to pull a pcap.  It successfully pulls a PCAP as expected, but not in a readable format for something like Wireshark.  Being a Python noob, I am not sure whatelse I need to do in order for the proper pcap format to come down.  Thanks in advance:

```
def observation_pcap(obsid,fname=None):

url = api_uri + "pcaps/observations/" + str(obsid)
headers = api_headers
action = requests.get(url,headers=headers,stream=True,timeout=10)

if fname == None:
    fname = str(obsid + ".pcap")

print(obsid)
print(fname)

with open(fname,'wb') as f:
    f.write(action.content)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with this module? What's the end goal?

Comment: Downloading a pcap

Comment: Can't you use the usual packet capturing tools (e.g., tcpdump)? Here, `action.content` returns the body of the HTTP answer. A pcap contains the data link layer flux (e.g., Ethernet frames). Although you can generate **a** pcap that corresponds to the HTTP answer (by generating the missing information and with much more code than you currently have), there's no way to retrieve **the actual** pcap that corresponds to your HTTP answer.

Comment: I’m not trying to capture traffic. The pcap is already created from a threat event in the cloud service I am making a call to. I’m trying to download that pcap with the API call via this python module.

Comment: Oh, I see. It shouldn't matter that it's a pcap file then. If you were downloading an image, it should be the same code (except for the file extension of course). The Python code looks ok; are you able to download the pcap file if you manually navigate to that URL?

Comment: Yes, if I run the API call in via curl it works fine.  However doing it via a python script, the pcap comes down in an unreadable format.  So I am trying to figure out what I might be missing in the Python script in order to make sure the pcap isn't modified in any way when it's downloaded.

Comment: Is the unreadable-with-wireshark file you retrieve a binary file or does it contain text? Is it a portion of the file you should get?